# Find a sequence from $L^1$ that is orthogonal to $1/|k|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, lp-spaces, orthogonality

If I have a sequence $W_k$ that belongs to $L¹$, then that means the series $\sum_{}^{}W_k$ is absolutely convergent. Now I need to find such a sequence, in a way that it is orthogonal to the sequence defined by $\frac{1}{|k|}$.

So, by the definition of orthogonality, in need $$\sum_{k =-\infty }^{+\infty }\frac{1}{|k|}W_k = 0, k \neq 0$$ (This exercise does not specify the space, so I'm assuming it's infinite).

So I can write this as $$2\sum_{k = 1 }^{+\infty }\frac{1}{k}W_k = 0$$

Now, how do I find a non trivial solution to $W_k$?

Comment: Think of the integral of even and odd functions as an analog

Comment: Is it allowed to choose all but a finite number of $W_k$ to be zero?

Comment: @paulinho It doesn't specify. So i guess we're free to assume?

Comment: @Dunham are you suggesting any odd function will do? (As long as it's series is absolutely convergent)

Comment: In that case, what about $W_1 = 1, W_2 = -2$ and all other $W_k = 0$?

Comment: @paulinho if $W_k = \left(-1\right)^{k-1}k$ then it would not belong to $L^1$.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused (I'm not too well-versed in this material); what requirement is not fulfilled by the example I gave and why?

Comment: @paulinho for a sequence $S_n$ to belong to an $L^p$ space, the series $\sum_{}^{}|S_n|^p$ must converge. (If in not mistaken)

Comment: @DanielOscar For my series, $\sum |W_k| = |1| + |-2| = 3$.

Comment: @paulinho alright, sorry, I misread your 2nd comment. Well I guess that works? But If I was sure, I wouldn't be here. Thanks, tho!

Comment: @DanielOscar That is exactly what I am saying.